# Xamarin Android FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException

Tags: xamarin, mono, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, unhandled-exception

I am getting some unhandeled exceptions that I don't understand. It is a Xamarin Forms App With PCL. First time in Debug mode I get error (see below), but when I stop debugging and run the app again in debug mode then it runs perfectly fine.

This repeats always, so third time it throws an error and forth time it works again.

> 01-19 15:43:44.073 D/Mono    (11226): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_boolean_method_a'.
>   01-19 15:43:44.073 D/Mono    (11226): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_boolean_method_a'.
>   01-19 15:43:44.073 D/Mono    (11226): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_boolean_method_a'.
>   01-19 15:43:44.073 D/Mono    (11226): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_boolean_method_a'.
>   01-19 15:43:44.083 D/Mono    (11226): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android[0x5bc61830] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Design[0x5b7bd630]: 2
>   01-19 15:43:44.093 D/Mono    (11226): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android[0x5bc61830] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView[0x5ba85088]: 2
>   01-19 15:43:44.103 D/Mono    (11226): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Platform[0x5bc86768] -> Xamarin.Forms.Core[0x5bb61870]: 6
>   01-19 15:43:44.183 I/dalvikvm(11226): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup., referenced from method md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.PlatformRenderer.
>   01-19 15:43:44.183 W/dalvikvm(11226): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 20617: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;. (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;II)V
>   01-19 15:43:44.183 D/dalvikvm(11226): VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
>   01-19 15:43:44.223 I/Choreographer(11226): Skipped 152 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   01-19 15:43:44.233 D/Mono    (11226): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
>   01-19 15:43:44.233 D/Mono    (11226): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_static_int_method_a'.
>   01-19 15:43:44.233 D/Mono    (11226): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_static_int_method_a'.
>   01-19 15:43:44.233 D/Mono    (11226): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_static_int_method_a'.
>   01-19 15:43:44.273 E/HAL     (11226): hw_get_module_by_class path = /system/lib/hw/gralloc.msm8960.so
>   An unhandled exception occured.
>
> 01-19 15:43:46.396 D/Mono    (11226): DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
>   01-19 15:43:46.396 D/Mono    (11226): DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
>   01-19 15:43:46.396 D/Mono    (11226): DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/liblog.so' ('/system/lib/liblog.so').
>   01-19 15:43:46.396 D/Mono    (11226): Searching for '__android_log_print'.
>   01-19 15:43:46.396 D/Mono    (11226): Probing '__android_log_print'.
>   01-19 15:43:46.396 D/Mono    (11226): Found as '__android_log_print'.
>   01-19 15:43:46.406 I/MonoDroid(11226): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
>   01-19 15:43:46.436 I/MonoDroid(11226): System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   01-19 15:43:46.436 I/MonoDroid(11226):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.LayoutRootPage (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height) [0x0005d] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\Platform.cs:279 
>   01-19 15:43:46.436 I/MonoDroid(11226):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IPlatformLayout.OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00003] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\Platform.cs:196 
>   01-19 15:43:46.436 I/MonoDroid(11226):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlatformRenderer.OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x0000e] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\PlatformRenderer.cs:73 
>   01-19 15:43:46.436 I/MonoDroid(11226):   at Android.Views.ViewGroup.n_OnLayout_ZIIII (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4009/9578cdcd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-25/src/generated/Android.Views.ViewGroup.cs:3427 
>   01-19 15:43:46.436 I/MonoDroid(11226):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:87bb057b-ab01-43e3-9911-e54de2defaf6 (intptr,intptr,bool,int,int,int,int)
>   01-19 15:43:46.466 D/Mono    (11226): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
>   01-19 15:43:46.466 D/Mono    (11226): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
>   01-19 15:43:46.466 D/Mono    (11226): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
>   01-19 15:43:46.466 D/Mono    (11226): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
>   An unhandled exception occured.
>
> 01-19 15:43:47.227 E/mono    (11226): 
>   01-19 15:43:47.227 E/mono    (11226): Unhandled Exception:
>   01-19 15:43:47.227 E/mono    (11226): System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   01-19 15:43:47.227 E/mono-rt (11226): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   In mgmain JNI_OnLoad

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: I solved this problem by adding a splashscreen in my PCL project, it is a normal xaml page with an activityindicator, my code will wait 2 seconds.